# No comments allowed

Tags: posts, comments

my posts won't allow commenting.  I have checked the discussion >  Allow comments and Allow trackbacks and pingbacks on this page in my post settings.
I also checked settings > discussion > Default article settings> Allow trackbacks and pingbacks on this page
I added a test comment on the post and it says comments are closed.  Did I forget to check something else?

Comment: Those options only set the defaults for new posts, if you change them you still have to go back to every post and enable comments on them individually

Comment: All of my posts have the options for commenting selected, but still they don't show up

Comment: We require more information,  Code! or URL!  without this its just a guessing game.

Please update the question with more information to help us determine the problem.  

A wild guess is comments have been striped from the theme, maybe from within the functions.php , could be outdated loops within the theme. maybe its being filtered as spam. Could be you are getting a cached page. A URL would be helpful

So many things it could be.

Comment: My url is (https://eyestigmatic.com/)

Comment: Are you sure your theme supports commenting? There's very little that can be done from the frontend only

Comment: Yes, this is the theme with the blog commenting - https://corinne.herparkstudio.com/8-things-avoid-on-social-media/

Comment: hmmm you never mentioned this was a premium theme, we can't provide dev support for a 3rd party theme ( note that any answers on this site are technical, this isn't a general support forum but a WP Dev QA site ). I'd suggest contacting herparkstudio support, otherwise you've already checked the stock WP options from what I've seen, but it could be another plugin or a theme option, no way of knowing without a search of the site from an administrator account. There really aren't many options left to explore..

Comment: thanks, I've contacted the theme designer and haven't heard back.  She's in Spain.  Thought I would try here.